# how to take updated input argument every time java

Tags: java

I am giving an input file as an argument which is stored outside jar .. The file gets updated content every 1hour can my program takes the file updated content automatically or Is there any way to get updated content from the file programatically without killing the jar...

Comment: Anji, Do you know about cron jobs, schedular tasks etc ?

Comment: Any reason for downvotes ?? Are we too harsh ? Where is the spirit of  #SOreadytohelp ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file watcher and simply reparse your file when a change is detected.  No need to restart your jar.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: Is there anything Like watch service in hadoop